# How to adjust textarea size with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I would like a text box be able to expand if the user clicks a button.  I know I have to use onclick function.  I know there are many examples with an auto adjusting textbox but I want the user to click it and it will expand and then save that data after they click a button to shrink it.

```
 <textarea rows="8" cols="80" id="queryText" name="query" requried>
</textarea>
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3rMM/ it won't give you the answer but it will definitely help you out

Comment: Why not use jQuery to add a class which modifies the size of your textbox?  Look at jQuery .focus() and .addClass()

Comment: @eugensunic I have seen that and right now my code expands but I want a button that when clicked will make the text box larger to add more data into it..

Comment: you need two buttons - one for increasing the size and one for saving the data in a textarea?

Comment: Save data where and why? Shrinking a textbox isn't going to make it lose data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size of a `textarea` by chaning the `cols` and `rows`. If you want to expand and then shrink back to normal size you could define them as:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("queryText");

var largeRows = "20";
var largeCols = "100";
var normalRows = textarea.rows; // Or smaller if you want this
var normalCols = textarea.cols; // to shrink more than normal.
```

And you could use a single button to resizing, changing the `value` or `innerHTML` of it to detect wheter you are expanding or shrinking:

*HTML*

```
<button id="size">+</button>
```

*JS*

```
document.getElementById("size").onclick = function()
{
    if(this.innerHTML == "+") {
        textarea.rows = largeRows;
        textarea.cols = largeCols;
        this.innerHTML = "-"
    } else {
        textarea.rows = normalRows;
        textarea.cols = normalCols;
        this.innerHTML = "+"
    }
}
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ox31ryoo/).

I don't think you need to save the data, as it will be there even if you shrink this or hide the `textarea`. But to get the text inside you can do `textarea.value`. And save it to a variable or `localStorage`, depending on you want to do.